# Identify collection of stories, which included Borge's Library story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

One of the stories was "The Library of Babel" by Borges, but I haven't been able to find any of the others among his works. Here is what I remember about some of them:

1. A man is walking along naked, his head is blown off by the wind. He (the head) comes to, looks around and sees his body standing motionless. By wiggling his jaw, he moves over to his body, then uses his teeth to climb up the side of his body until he can set his head back on his neck and continues his walk.
2. A man visits a gigantic waterfall, so large that no one has ever been to the top. While watching it he sees what looks like the remains of a huge disaster flow over, at the end the whole waterfall turns red.
3. A group of people with un-naturally pale skin, live as statues in museums.

There may have been others, but that is all I remember. They were all weird.

Comment: 2nd one is probably "By the Falls" by Harry Harrison.

Comment: Ok, I'm not confident enough to mark it as an answer, but how about [New Worlds of Fantasy #2](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23804)? The statue one might be "The Petrified World" or "A Museum Piece", can y'all find any more info on either?

Comment: Other descriptions of "By the Falls" match what I remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you remember one of the stories, look on [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/) to see [what collections it's been published in](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23804). One that looks promising is [*New Worlds of Fantasy #2*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23804), which includes:

- [“By the Falls”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54366) by Harry Harrison, definitely your second story.
- [“A Museum Piece”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58671) by Roger Zelazny, probably your third story.

Comment: Oooh, 1st story's probably [En Passant](http://books.google.com/books?ei=D_RkT_G9MeW00QGH85X-Bw&id=_FUbAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22Backward%2C+Turn+Backward%22+%22Wilmar+H.+Shiras%22&q=jaw#search_anchor) by Britt Schweitzer. It starts on Page 168 according to ISFDB, and the 2nd and 3rd snippets on Google seem to fit. Edited b/c I can't math.

Comment: That is it. Thanks a lot, not only for the answer but for the links to how to find others.